# Minimum diameter for $n$ points, given that distance between any two of them is greater than or equal to 1.

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

There are $n$ points on a plane, such that distance between any two of them $\geq 1$. Question is, what is minimum possible diameter for such set of points, that is minimum of distance between two farthest points. At first I thought optimal configuration would be regular $n$-gon with side 1. For this configuration the answer is $$\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}\cdot\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$

For $n=2,3$, this is obviously true, answer is $1$. 
however for $n=7$, There is a configuration with diameter $2$, regular hexagon with side $1$, and its center.

I can't prove that regular polygon is answer for $n=4,5,6$. But I still think that it is optimal, So how can I prove it for $n=4,5,6$ and what is the answer in general case?

Comment: For four, look at the diagonals of the convex hull of the four points. Since all sides are $\geq1$, if the diagonals are $<\sqrt{2}$, then by the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) the angles are $<\pi/2$. Therefore, the interior angles wouldn't add up to $2\pi$. Well, I assumed that the convex hull was a quadrilateral. The cases in which the convex hull is a triangle, or a segment are similar, but easier.

Comment: I also realized that for $n=6$, regular pentagon with side $1$ and its center has diameter of $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{10})=1.90211...$, so regular hexagon is not optimal